# Why is terminate() called even if the unexpected_handler() throws a specified exception?

Tags: c++, exception

Consider the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

void third_party_function() throw () {
    throw -1; // oops
}

void recover() throw (std::exception) {
    std::cout << "We will throw std::exception() to avoid terminate() to be called.\n";
    throw std::exception();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    try {
        std::set_unexpected(recover);
        third_party_function();
    } catch (std::exception e) {
         std::cout << "Unexpected exception: " << e.what() << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This the output from the program:

> We will throw std::exception() to avoid terminate() to be called.
>   **terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::exception'**
>   what():  std::exception

I don't understand why terminate() is called in any case (therefore the std::exception is never caught) despite of the fact that I did what Stroustrup suggests with a similar example to avoid terminate() to be called after the handler has been called (see C++ Programming Language, 3rd edition, chapter 14.6)

Comment: The cake is a lie.  Doesn't make much sense to not document the CRT you are using.

Comment: What does CRT stand for?

Comment: C RunTime.  Document what compiler and operating system you are using.

Comment: Linux 2.6.31-22-generic-pae #73-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 11 18:39:01 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux
gcc version 4.4.1
Using built-in specs.
Target: i486-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix

Answer (score 2):

The `third_party_function` promises to not throw any exception whatsover.

Thus any exception whatsoever, of type `int` or `std::exception` doesn't matter, causes a call to `std::terminate`, per C++98 §15.5.2/2.

If it had instead limited itself to `std::bad_exception`, then with a conforming implementation the new exception would be automatically translated to `std::bad_exception`.

In the current standard C++11 the use of this kind of exception specification, using the keyword `throw`, is deprecated.

C++11 does however have the same wording as C++98 about the effect, in C++11 §15.5.2/3.

Also, note that while Visual C++ does allow the syntax, it has never honored the semantics (except possibly for nothrow, which is now documented as equivalent to using a language extension that says no exceptions).

Thus, while it's still valid standard C++, it is in practice non-portable if the exception specifications are relied on for any specific effect except nothrow.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to have the unexpected handler throw an exception within the exception specification list. Since `third_party_function` exception specification is no exceptions thrown, it won't work. However if `third_party_function` had `std::exception` within its exception specification your code would work.

Exception specifications have been deprecated in C++11, perhaps you shouldn't be using them.

Comment: No, `third_party_function() throw (std::exception)` does not change this behavior. Even removing the exception specification altogether does not change it (tested on Visual C++ 2010).

Comment: @Branko Dimitrijevic: Testing in VC++2010 is useless, MSVC never did and never will respect exception specifications.

Comment: Then how come `recover()` is not called?

Comment: @Branko: it's a case of user error. Visual C++ don't support exception specifications except nothrow, so you get the `int` type exception propagating right up into `main`, where it's not handled. You should have tested with the compiler you used at first. Oh, I see you're not the OP. But anyway...

Comment: @K-ballo But the fact that `int` exception is unhandled should have triggered `recover()`, right?

Comment: @Branko Dimitrijevic: It did for the OP using GCC. It won't in MSVC since it does not support exception specifications. MSVC only considers `throw()` as an optimization, but it does not enforce exception specificatoins at all.

Comment: @K-ballo For some reason, I though `set_unexpected` was relevant for unhandled exceptions too (hence ensuing confusion about why `recover()` was not called), but I see now that it is only relevant for the "throw list", which as you rightfully point out, is unsupported by MSVC. I learned something useful today, thank you.